# i am getting error on The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.11.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0' or higher to enable null safety. and red lines on flat button,

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Today, I got a job after struggling so much, Now they asked me to clone a project from master file and run the project,  from past two days i ma trying hard to run the project but i am getting errors like in whole project i am getting error on snackbarshow, flatbutton, raisedbutton, and zoomopion, they are on red lines, and also i am getting error on dependencies like Resolving dependencies...
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.11.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0'
or higher to enable null safety.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Aj9.png)

The current Dart SDK (3.0.3) only supports null safety.

i have tried almos every solution on google like changing sdk version in pubspecyml file and also upgrade my flutter too, here is my flutter info: i am using andriod studio, Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 3.10.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 682aa387cf (2 days ago) • 2023-06-05 18:04:56 -0500
Engine • revision 2a3401c9bb
Tools • Dart 3.0.3 • DevTools 2.23.1

Comment: is the error tied to any of your packages or dependencies, if it is, you can upgrade those packages.

Comment: i have tried to upgrade packages as well but keep getting error The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0'
or higher to enable null safety.

The current Dart SDK (3.0.3) only supports null safety.

Comment: Have you tried using the `sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'` ?

Comment: yes i tried it it is not working

Comment: please check the image url in description

Answer (score 1):

It seems this project was made with a very old version of flutter. Before null-safety. If I'm not mistaken they introduced that in version 2.0.0 of flutter and the version before that is 1.22.6. If you don't want to migrate your project to make the project compatible with the latest flutter you can try to run it with flutter 1.22.6. Unfortunately it's not very straightforward how to do that. What you can try to do is open a command prompt and go the folder where your flutter sdk is located and write

```
git checkout 1.22.6
```

After that try a

```
flutter doctor
```

in your project, and see if it changed it to the right flutter version.

This is not guaranteed to work, but it's worth a try, although I think there's only a small chance that this works. If it doesn't work I'm afraid you will need to refactor the project to make it work with the latest flutter version. If you want to revert the change that `git checkout 1.22.6` did simply do

```
flutter channel stable
```

and

```
flutter upgrade
```

from your project.

Comment: it is not working, can i use older version of flutter to run the project? if yes then how and which version please help me

Comment: and please please check the image url in description

Comment: i tried your method and getting this error now , The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.5.

Because flutter_zoom_sdk <0.0.5 depends on args >=2.0.0-nullsafety.0 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <4.0.0, flutter_zoom_sdk <0.0.5 is forbidden.
So, because flutter_zoom_sdk >=0.0.5 requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0 and hmb_project depends on flutter_zoom_sdk any, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because flutter_zoom_sdk >=0.0.5 requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0 and hmb_project depends on flutter_zoom_sdk any, version solving failed.)

Answer (score 0):

Its Better to change the **flutter_zoom_sdk** **as its out of date and causing errors.**
try using=> **zoom: ^1.0.4** or add the **general zoom SDK for each platform using method channel**. Its also recommended to update all the packages to **Dart 3 compatible** versions for avoiding future issues. Also Use ***dart fix --dry-run*** to see suggested changes and ***dart fix --apply*** to apply them.